# Hide VSCode snippets in suggestion list when no code is written?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode there is a setting for having snippets first in the list of suggestions (`"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",`).  This is great, as you might want a snippet to take precedence over other intellisense items when it matches what you've written.

However, the snippets will also be ordered at the top when you display suggestions without writing anything. I often show suggestions inside classes to see what properties/methods I have available, but in those cases I have to scroll through my entire list of snippets before the properties/methods show up. Is there any way to turn off snippet suggestions when you have not written anything?

Example image of the suggestions showing above halfway down in the suggestion list:

[image: Image showing the available properties above halfway down in the suggestion list]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an option as of yet, and a feature request for this funtionality has been added. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147357

In the meantime, a workaround is to hide snippets from completions and use the explicit `> Insert Snippet` command instead. (Copied from the issue response)

Comment: update: closed as out of scope